# A natural work with Missing values

Tags: probability-or-statistics, missing

For statistical procedures, is there some simple setting to automatically skip the Missing values? (e.g. Options -> "SkipMissing")

The naive

```
 Mean[{1, 2, 3, Missing[], 5, 6}]
```

leads to the `1/6 (17 + Missing[])`

I know the way of preparing the list, e.q.

```
 Mean[{1, 2, 3, Missing[], 5, 6} // DeleteMissing]
```

but I'm looking for a less cumbersome way, especially for complex procedures or procedures with Datasets. Some as

```
Mean[{1, 2, 3, Missing[], 5, 6}, MissingOptions-> SkipMissing]
```

but more universal, working with multivariate statistic et.c.

Comment: You could define something like this: `withoutMissing = 
 Function[code, Block[{Missing = Nothing}, code], HoldFirst]`, and use as e.g. `withoutMissing @ Mean[{1, 2, 3, Missing[], 5, 6}]`, or generally wrap `withoutMissing` around any code where you want `Missing` values to be removed. Not totally sure how robust this method is, but you can try it.

Comment: `Query[Mean][{1, 2, 3, Missing[], 5, 6}]`?

Comment: `Mean[{1, 2, 3, Missing[], 5, 6} /. Missing -> Nothing]`

Comment: I have the same question. Did you come up with a solution / work around?